# PHP include file variables losing scope

Tags: php, class, object, scope, include

Inside a class, I have a method that reads a few variables from an external file. I then set member variables using these included variables. As soon as this method completes however, the member variables get reset to null. What am I doing wrong?

main.php

```
$bob = new Object();
$bob->init();
echo $bob->value;
```

Object.php

```
public function init() {
include('/includefile.inc');
$this->value = $included_value;
echo $this->value;
}
```

includefile.inc

```
<? $included_value = 'Hello World'; ?>
```

The echo inside Object.php will work correctly, but the echo outside in main will be null. value is a public variable inside the Object.php class definition.

Comment: you want to return the value in the function , not echo it

Comment: Both should echo perfectly fine.

Comment: I shouldn't need to return it; it's being assigned to a class variable. That's what $this->value = $included_value is supposed to do, right?

Comment: They **should** echo perfectly fine, but the one outside does not. Hence my confusion. :/

Comment: By should, I meant that I tested it and it works fine (assuming you defined the class correctly in Object.php). Do you get any errors? Also, you should probably post your full, minimal, verifiable example.

Comment: Can you show the full code for `Object.php` please?

Comment: [link] (http://paste.ofcode.org/32PK3vsXwQXMiSNmFK8QYct) Here you go!

Answer (score 1):

Quoted directly from the manual...

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope.

Hence....

```
public function init() {
 $included_value=false;
 include('/includefile.inc');
 $this->value = $included_value;
 echo $this->value;
}
```

Should work as you expect.

Comment: Yes, but I'm calling echo outside the init(), using an object reference. So, echo $object->value.

Comment: The variable `$included_value` *is not referenced* prior to the include statement so *does not exist* when include is invoked.

Comment: the variable `$included_value` is inside the included file.

Comment: Yes, so `all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope.`